# Plotting datafile with abbreviated values with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot datafile that looks like this:

```
 1  4810   582   573   587 
 2    99k   67k   56k   40k
 3   119k   82k   68k   49k
 4   119k   81k   68k   49k
 5   120k   81k   65k   45k
 6   121k   82k   65k   44k
 7   124k  106k   97k   86k
 8   128k  134k  131k  131k
 9   128k  130k  131k  135k
10   129k  133k  130k  132k
```

First column will be on the X-axis labeled as "Time", the rest are the different interrupt values with respect to time (i.e. IRQ1, IRQ2, IRQ3, IRQ4)

The problem when generating a plot with this is that gnuplot does not seem to interpret the abbreviated values with the K suffix as numbers in the thousands, but instead as raw values such as 99, 67, 119, etc. Thus the lines will jump from around 5000 at time 1 and drop to around 100 in the graph.

Are there any options to tell gnuplot to automatically interpret abbreviated values and plot them accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no direct way of telling gnuplot of how to interpret the input in this case.

You can, however, write your own function that converts the string-input to numbers

```
check(x)=(pos=strstrt(x,"k"),\
    pos > 0 ? real(substr(x,1,pos-1))*1000  : real(x))
```

The function `check` first determines the position of the letter 'k' in the input. (The function `strstrt` returns '0' if the input `x` does not contain the letter 'k'.)
If the input contains the letter 'k', take the input, discard the last letter, convert the remaining part to a number and multiply it by 1000.
If the input does not contain 'k', return the input

Now you can plot the data file (assuming its name is `test`):

```
plot 'test' u 1:(check(stringcolumn(2))) w l
```

[image]

This should do the job!

Comment: I had gnuplot 4.2 and was not able to reproduce the function as you've described due to syntax errors. However, after updating it to version 4.4 it works fine.

Comment: @Decrypto: I'm glad that your problem is solved. Upgrading certainly was a good idea (considering that 4.2 was released in 2007).
But even Version 4.4 is pretty old (2010). If everything works for you with 4.4, stay with it. But keep in mind that the current version is 5.0 (released 2015)

Answer (score 2):

a non-purely gnuplot, unix solution would use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
plot "<(sed 's/k/000/g' datafile.dat)" u 1:2 w lp
```

The `sed 's/k/000/g'` command replaces all occurrences of the character `k` with `000` in `datafile.dat`: e.g. 96k will be replaced with 96000.

The output is similar to the plot posted by @Knorr