# gnuplot: How to parse input numbers with unit suffixes (m/g for mega/gigabytes)?

Tags: gnuplot

In the data of memory usage over time, the memory size is in bytes `<megabytes>m` or `<gigas>g`. How to tell Gnuplot that if it sees `<number>m` it should multiply the number by 1024^2 and 1024^3 for the `g` suffix?

Example:

```
0
360m
1.1g
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked for improvements, here you go:

```
resolveUnit(s)=(pos=strstrt("kmgtp",s[strlen(s):*]), real(s)*(1024**pos))
print resolveUnit("123.0")
print resolveUnit("1k")
print resolveUnit("2m")
print resolveUnit("4g")
```

This uses the position of the unit suffix as exponent for `1024`. During the calculation, the suffix is silently discarded by `real`, `real('100k') => 100.0`

Comment: Genial! ❤️Thanks a lot! The trick to get the last character is really neat. And I did not know that `real` will take care of dropping the unit. Really nice and simple!

Comment: AFAIK, gnuplot internally parses numbers with `atof` from `stdlib.h` and behaves accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Use the UNIX command `sed` to replace these letters with multipliers in the new column.

```
 plot "< sed 's/\\([^kmg]\\)$/\\1 1/;s/k$/ 1024/;s/m$/ 1048576/;s/g$/ 1073741824/' data.dat" u ($1*$2) w lp notitle
```

The data handled by gnuplot will look like this:

```
0 1
360 1048576
1.1 1073741824
```

Then this data will be plotted using multiplication of the first and second column: `u ($1*$2)`.

[image]

If you are using Windows, `sed` can be found [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

Comment: Thanks, that is an interesting approach, and simpler than my final gnuplot-only solution. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing, essentially an extension of a similar solution [posted earlier by F. Knorr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507660/plotting-datafile-with-abbreviated-values-with-gnuplot?rq=1) (notice that the sizes with unit markers are in column 2 in my data):

```
resolveUnit(u,mul,x)=(pos=strstrt(x,u), pos > 0 ? sprintf("%f",real(substr(x,1,pos - 1))*mul) : x)
resolveUnits(x)=(resolveUnit("g",1024*1024*1024,resolveUnit("m",1024*1024,x)))
check(x)=(real(resolveUnits(x)))
plot infile using 1:(check(stringcolumn(2)))
```

I am sure this code can be improved a lot. Don't hesitate to comment :-)

I would like to look into adapting the neat approach from [this AWK solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/237412/handy-parsing-for-numbers-with-unit-suffixes/237451#237451) to support other units than m and g but won't have time for that.